# Logistic regression-like model for non-discrete outcomes

Tags: r, probability, logistic, generalized-linear-model

If I have a set of continuous predictors $X$ and a binary outcome $Y$ and I wanted to build a predictive model of $P(Y|X)$, I would start with a logistic regression model.

However, in my particular case, my $Y$ isn't binary, it's continuous between 0 and 1.  Is there a similar Generalized Linear Model that can be applied in this case?  My optimistic/naive attempt in R reveals that

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(y=runif(8), x1=rnorm(8), x2=rnorm(8))
mod <- glm(y ~ ., data=df, family=binomial('logit'))

# Warning message:
# In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!

rbind(yhat=predict(mod, newdata=df), y=df$y)
#              1         2          3         4         5          6         7           8
# yhat 0.7461449 0.4869853 -0.1092115 1.9854276 0.8328304 -1.3708688 1.0150934 -0.03496334
# y    0.2875775 0.7883051  0.4089769 0.8830174 0.9404673  0.0455565 0.5281055  0.89241904
```

Note that some of the predictions are outside of $(0,1)$.  Any suggestions?

Comment: As to why some of the predictions are outside (0,1): this is because the result of `predict.glm()` is by default on the link scale, not the response scale. Try `rbind(yhat=predict(mod, newdata=df, type="response"), y=df$y)` and `?predict.glm`, and enlightenment will follow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have "continuous" (seemingly, as they could still be discrete) values in between 0 and 1 there are at least two cases:

1. They came from a number of independent binary trials and the "continuous" value is the number of successes divided by trials. Then a binomial GLM might be appropriate. In this case you need to fit it in R as `glm(cbind(numberSuccesses,numberFailures)~x,family=binomial)`
2. If that is not the case, then you might have something for which a [Beta Model](http://epub.wu.ac.at/726/) might be more appropriate. The link I provided shows how to do that in R.

Note that in R `glm(y~x,family=binomial)` with a "continuous" $y$ will throw a warning and in general the result will not be the same as in the case with number of successes and trials:

```
set.seed(1)
successes<-sample(1:10,100,replace=TRUE)
x<-1:100
n<-12
failures<-n-successes

summary(glm(cbind(successes,failures)~x,family=binomial))
Call:
glm(formula = cbind(successes, failures) ~ x, family = binomial)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.8197  -0.9434   0.0454   0.9358   2.4921  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -0.24622    0.11349   -2.17     0.03 *
x            0.00080    0.00195    0.41     0.68  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 134.99  on 99  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 134.82  on 98  degrees of freedom
AIC: 422.2

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

but

```
props<-successes/n
summary(glm(props~x,family=binomial))

Call:
glm(formula = props ~ x, family = binomial)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-0.852  -0.282  -0.105   0.394   0.760  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -0.134339   0.403836   -0.33     0.74
x            0.000281   0.006941    0.04     0.97

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 20.888  on 99  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 20.887  on 98  degrees of freedom
AIC: 141.3

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3

Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
```

Comment: Thanks, @Momo.  In my case a binomial doesn't really fit, these "probabilities" are actually somewhat subjective and involve a human judgment in their creation.  I'm taking a look at the Beta Regression technique, it's going to take a while for me to figure out how to use it appropriately though.

Comment: Glad if it helped. Beta regression probably does it for you then, and its R implementation is very similar to the GLM model family. Good luck.

Comment: How does GLM fit in the 2nd case (in which the warning is given)? Where can I find any reference?

Comment: @colinfang I'm afraid you need to look at the source code to check that, as this is probably non-standard (Personally it should throw an error, not a warning).

Comment: Your two examples now yield the same coefficient estimates (i.e., both approaches give intercept=-0.134339 and x=0.000281), but estimates' precision varies.